# How much time do I have to shut down gracefully my .NET worker application? Is it configurable?

Tags: c#, worker, background-service

Lets have this WorkerSample application:

Program.cs

```
using WorkerSample;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
Console.WriteLine("Program terminated");
```

Worker.cs:

```
namespace WorkerSample;

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker executing ...");
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, stoppingToken);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }

        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(25000);
            Console.WriteLine("I have shut down gracefully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error shutting down gracefully \n {ex.ToString()}");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finally block called");
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this app on .NET 6.0 and press Ctrl+C:

with `await Task.Delay(5000)` I see the following output:

```
Worker executing ...
I have shut down gracefully
Finally block called
Program terminated
```

So I have at least 5 seconds for shutting down gracefully.

With `await Task.Delay(6000)` I see the following output:

```
Worker executing ...
Program terminated
```

So I have less than 6 seconds for shutting down gracefully

In .NET 7.0 things changed. I have al least 25 seconds and less than 30 seconds for shutting down gracefully.

How much time do I have for shutting down gracefully? Does it depend only .NET version? Is it configurable?

Comment: Where are you getting the phrase "shooting down" from?  Are you trying to stop a service?  There are certainly graceful ways to do that.  The amount of time it takes to stop a service depends on a number of factors; it depends on what the service is doing when you try to stop it, how long it takes to "spin down" dependent services, etc.

Comment: @Robert Harvey
If you create a .NET worker application. `dotnet new worker` execute it, and press Ctrl+C you see the following on the console `info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Application is shutting down...`

Comment: You can set the default timeout for stopping with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostoptions.shutdowntimeout

Comment: "Shutting down," not "Shooting down."

Comment: @VadimMartynov could you make your comment an answer?. Just ad a call to .ConfigureHostOptions to IHostBuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`HostOptions.ShutdownTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostoptions.shutdowntimeout) stores the default timeout for [`IHost.StopAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihost.stopasync) method. [Default timeout](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/63712/files) is 5 seconds for .NET Core and .NET 5 and 30 seconds for .NET 6 and .NET 7.

`StopAsync` is called when the application receives the shut down (`SIGTERM`) signal, for example when you push `CTRL+C` in the console window, or the app is stopped by the host system. This allows you to close any open connections, dispose resources, and generally clean up your class as required.

`HostOptions` isn't explicitly configured anywhere by default, so you will need to configure it manually. For example, the following config increases the timeout to 15s:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.Configure<HostOptions>(
                opts => opts.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    })
    .Build();
```

Alternatively, you can also load the timeout from configuration. For example, if you add the following to appsettings.json:

```
{
    "HostOptions": {
        "ShutdownTimeout": "00:00:15"
    }
    // other config
}
```

You can then bind the HostOptions configuration section to the HostOptions object:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
builder.Services.Configure<HostOptions>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("HostOptions"));
```

Comment: What about this: `IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .ConfigureHostOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    })
    .Build();`